# does codesourcery include secure version of standard functions (strcpy_s,sprintf_s etc.)

Tags: gcc, codesourcery, secure-coding

Quick question: I use codesourcery g++ lite for arm-none-eabi. I made a  search in the include folder to see if there is secure function like strcpy_s and sprintf_s, but I got no result.

Does codesourcery provide theses secure function (maybe under a different name?)

On the Mentor Graphics web site I didn't found an answer to this question (either on google...).

Do I have to add a third party version of this functions in my project?

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy_s` and `sprintf_s` are not standard C++ functions but C11 fonctions.

Even in C11, they are an optional extension and so not required to be present.